# Post images from external url without input[type='file'] (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, api, image-uploading, external-url

I'm working with **Laravel 5.3** and I have problem with post images to my api. I have external urls of images which come from social network api.

My Task is get this all items and post it to api without any `form`, `input` elements just from controller.

I fetch image from api and I can easily post text values but I struggle with images. I can use `Image::make()` and make image from url;

```
$orig = pathinfo($media['image_url'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$extension = substr($orig, 0, strpos($orig, '?'));
$filename = time().'-'.str_random(20).'.'.$extension;
// make image 
$img = Image::make($media['image_url']);
```

if I return this `$img` I got this object:

[image]

But I don't need to save it. I have to send it direct to api. If I try to set this object to `$request->files` array where I receive `POST` `$request` before I save to `DB` in I got this error:

[image]

But I want to set this image like that for able to use as uploadedFile:

[image]

How can I do this. I don't have any idea. Thanks! :)

Comment: It depends on what image format the external url/API you're posting to accept, if possible just convert the image into base64 before sending it

Comment: yeah,I`ll try it,. Thanks for reply, man :)